# Vue + Laravel 8 Vue Fetch API POST request body value not obtained in HTTP request

Tags: laravel, vue.js

***Note: post request does reach the route but my params array is empty. I am not getting any request errors. My route code is in api.php. Get request works. While it works when requested from Postman***

Can anyone please tell me what am I missing here? I have gone through some examples available and have done the same thing in code but still no success. Thanks in advance.

**This is my Laravel route code**

```
Route::post('/addtask', function (Request $request) {
    $params = $request->except('_method', '_token');       
    try {
        return Upcoming::create([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'taskId' => $request->taskId,
            'waiting' => $request->waiting
        ]);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        return  $ex->getMessage();
    }
});
```

**This is my Vue code**

```
const task = {
    title: this.newTask,
    waiting: true,
    taskId: Math.random().toString(36).substring(7),
};
fetch("/api/addtask", {
    method: "POST",
    header: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",            
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(task)          
})
.then(() => this.upcoming.push(task))
.catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

**It was silly mistake by me. change header to headers in vue code.**

Comment: try using HTTP client such as postman, does it work?

Comment: yes. It is working. I have not written that in question I will update it. Any other reason why I am not getting any value in $request.

Comment: what is the response code and if there is any error message in the response please add it too

Comment: I am not getting any errors neither it is related to any error. My $request object is empty or can say after removing _mehod and _token from $request $params variable is empty. am I missing something in laravel or vue.

Comment: try to return as `response()->json()`

Comment: Bro. you are not getting my question. It is not related to response neither any error.

Comment: i know you said that you get an empty array in your vue app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231810/discussion-between-joseph-and-rahul-baraiya).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on [`MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options) there is no option called `header` it is called `headers`

```
fetch("/api/addtask", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",            
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(task)          
})
```